# What prevents template deduction from working with std::function as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, c++17

What is it about template type deduction that prevents the compiler from determining the intended type when invoking fubar the first time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename A>
void fubar(std::function<int(A&)>) {
    printf("fubar1\n");
}

struct foo {
    int bar() { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    fubar(&foo::bar);      // This won't compile. Why can't the compiler figure it out?
    fubar<foo>(&foo::bar); // But this will - which makes sense
}
```

Comment: Template deduction is always on the exact type passed in. It doesn't consider conversions. You can construct a `std::function` from a function pointer, but they are not the same type.

Comment: So I think that's really the answer here. My mistake here was in thinking that template deduction could also participate along with considering conversions. The conversion can't be considered until the type has been specified. There's probably a more precise standard'eze way to express this.